# What variant of using UnitOfWork in service is more proper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

Good day!

My system has N-Layer architecture:

- DAL (Data Access Layer) (Entity Framework 6, Repositories,
  UnitOfWork)
- BLL (Busisness Logic Layer)
- PL (Presentation layer) (ASP.NET MVC 4)

The question is as follows:

**What variant of UnitOfWork using is more proper?**

First variant (characteristic’s use, explicitly call Dispose() in controller ASP.NET MVC):

```
namespace MyApp.BLL.Services
{
    public class MyService
    {
    private UnitOfWork _uow { get; set; }

    public MyService()
    {
      _uow = new UnitOfWork();
    }

    public List<SomeDTO> SomeGetMethod()
    {
      IEnumerable<Entity> entities = _uow.SomeRepository.Get(x => x.Id==1);
      ...
      return ...
    }

    public void SomeSetMethod(int value)
    {
      _uow.SomeRepository.Insert(new Entity { Value = value });

      _uow.Commit(); // SaveChanges();
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
      _uow.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Second variant (using block):

```
namespace MyApp.BLL.Services
{
    public class MyService
    {
    public List<SomeDTO> SomeGetMethod()
    {
      using(UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
      {
        IEnumerable<Entity> entities = uow.SomeRepository.Get(x => x.Id==1);
      }
      ....
      return ...
    }

    public void SomeSetMethod(int value)
    {
      using(UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
      {
        uow.SomeRepository.Insert(new Entity { Value = value });

        uow.Commit(); // SaveChanges();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the second question:

For example we have a service, which is responsible for message module work in system - IMessagesService and we also have second service, which is responsible for  some module - ISomeService. In result of making a method in service ISomeService it’s necessary to send a message in system. Will it be correct to call method of another IMessagesService for sending a message?

Example:

```
public interface IMessagesService
{
  void Send(int userFrom, int userTo, string message);
  // other methods...
}

public class MessageService
{
  public void Send(int userFrom, int userTo, string message)
  {
    // some logic here
  }
}

public interface ISomeService
{
  void SomeMethod(int somevalue);
}

public class SomeService: ISomeService
{
  public void SomeMethod(int somevalue)
  {
    // some logic here

    // после необходимо отправить сообщение
    messageService = new MessageService();
    messageService.Send(1, 2, "some text");
  }
}
```

**In another words- is it correct to call from one service method of second service?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The private variable unitofwork I think is a better approach, as it leans more towards Inversion of control but the control is not injected, and the Using block approach to me shoudn't be done in the services them selves. 
The unitofwork object should be injected, and controlled elsewhere. IMO the entire point of a unitofwork pattern is to encapsulate a transaction scope. This transaction scope should be able to span services. Good encapsulation principle direct us into making atomic services, that are singular focused (SOLID). i.e. in your case, everything to do with Messages should be in the message service, and rightly so. But as you've seen, because of this principle, other services may need to send a message. So yes, I think it is not unreasonable for one service to call another, especially if there is business rules that need to be enforced. In fact multiple services going to the same repository to potentially do the same thing violates DRY IMO.
 I also think it would be desired behaviour to not send a message if there is a failure, or rollback the first action (what ever it may be) if the message sending fails. You could of course test for this (if.. then .. type pattern), and potentially manually write rollback code (ugly!) but wrapping up all of the services you are using with the same unitofwork means you have a rollback (and commit) type approach anyway (especially if you are using an ORM mapper, i.e. Entity Framework), and lots of embedded if statements can be a bit of a code smell IMO.

So you are not injecting the unitofwork into the services, so your transaction scope is limited only to the service it is created in. Also makes it more difficult to test. All of these issues are exactly the same things I am going through right now on another project, which follows the same code structure/approach, and I will be the first say, I haven't found a perfect approach yet either but I would approach it something more like this:

```
//Base service class to take the unit of work injection
public abstract class BaseService
    {
    private IUnitOfWork _uow { get; private set; }

    public BaseService(IUnitOfWork scope)
    {
      _uow = scope;
    }
}
```

and then service class implementations

```
public class SomeService: BaseService, ISomeService
{
    public MyService(IUnitOfWork scope) : base(scope)
    {

    }
  public void SomeMethod(int somevalue)
  {

    //Do something in this service
    //code here.....

   //then do something in the next service, passing though 
    //the same unitof work

    messageService = new MessageService(_uow );
    messageService.Send(1, 2, "some text");
  }
}
```

This passes the responsiblity of controlling the unitofwork (scope) to the caller. In your case the PL presentation layer, or for ease of testing another test class if you wish. From PL something like:

```
//PL Controller that does something cool
public class BaseService : Controller
{

    public ActionResult DoSomething(int value)
    {
        using(IUnitOfWork scope = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            ISomeService theService = new SomeService(scope);
            theService.SomeMethod(value);
        }
        ...con
    }

}
```

I actually put another layer inbetween PL and BLL to control the scope, and Dependancy inject the services, sort of a unitofworkcontroller if you will.

Anyway my two cents

Comment: Why do you `new()` up `UnitOfWork` and `SomeService`? If we are talking about DI, then you would inject their interfaces to `BaseService` constructor.

Comment: @OJay Thanks!  You said: _I actually put another layer inbetween PL and BLL to control the scope, and Dependancy inject the services, sort of a unitofworkcontroller if you will_.  Can u show me example of this layer please? And `PL` shouldn't reference `DAL` (UnitOfWork here), isn't right?